# Getting "Async write timed out after 5.000 s" in Akka

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-http, akka-cluster

Getting below error when Akka is getting multiple concurrent requests:

```
[ERROR] [09/14/2021 15:53:30.457] [test-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-22] [akka.cluster.sharding.Shard] - testserver: Remember entity store did not respond, restarting shard
[ERROR] [09/14/2021 15:53:30.457] [test-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-22] [akka.cluster.sharding.Shard] - testserver: Remember entity store did not respond, restarting shard
[ERROR] [09/14/2021 15:53:30.461] [test-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-22] [akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy] - Async write timed out after 5.000 s
java.lang.RuntimeException: Async write timed out after 5.000 s
    at akka.cluster.sharding.Shard$$anonfun$waitingForRememberEntitiesStore$1.applyOrElse(Shard.scala:684)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
    at akka.cluster.sharding.Shard.akka$actor$Timers$$super$aroundReceive(Shard.scala:409)
    at akka.actor.Timers.aroundReceive(Timers.scala:52)
    at akka.actor.Timers.aroundReceive$(Timers.scala:41)
    at akka.cluster.sharding.Shard.aroundReceive(Shard.scala:409)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:579)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:547)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

When do we get this error and how to fix it?

Comment: `receive` times out, obviously. Takes more than 5 seconds. You mentioned association with concurrent requests, so my guess is some badly written code in the actor causes a deadlock. Impossible to infer anything more than this without seeing the actual application code

Comment: Can you say more about what you tested and when you got this type error.That will be helpful to answer

Comment: This is happening in `waitingForRememberEntitiesStore` so I doubt this is user code issue. I'm having this same issue and it's then causing circuit breaker to open and fail-fast anything that reads or writes via the journal.